# Altering a value in a rdlc report through .aspx.cs C# code

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services, webforms, rdlc

First off I am using Microsoft Visual 2010 on windows 7, so I have .net 4.0 programming.

I have created an **ASP.NET** project and made an `.rdlc` report and it displays the data great, but I would like the report to display a title similar to:

All values from `[startDate]` to `[endDate]` for `[ID]`.
--Rest of Report in columns and rows--

From the .aspx web design page, the user enters the `startDate` and `endDate` into TextBox's: `TextBox1` and `TextBox2`.  Although the `startDate` and `endDate` is passed into a **SQL comman**d, it's not returned in the query as data to display.

Is there a way in the `aspx.cs` section of code (in C#) to change the values in the report itself using the `TextBox1.Values`.

Basically to set `[startDate]`(from the `.rdlc` report) to `TextBox1.Values` from the `.aspx` ... etc.

Something like (even though I know this is isn't correct):

```
ReportViewer1.startDate = TextBox1.Value;
```

Thanks for the help if any.

Edit:
I would post picks of what I am trying to do but I am new and reputation is to low it seems.

Basically in the .rdlc report I want to display in a TextBox.

Here are all the values for [Item] from the dates [startDate] to [endDate].

In a table in the report all the data is shown.

Example:

Here are all the values for TK421 from the dates 6/13/2014 to 2/3/2015.

```
Item | Value1 | Value2
TK421|  127   | 4
```

---

The web page is simply

```
Start Date  |  End Date  | Item
TextBox1    | TextBox2   | DropDownList1  | SearchButton
```

What I am simply trying to do is take the TextBox1 item from Start Date in the web page and put it in the [startDate] Field of the report.  I have yet to find a good source of information on how to do this with some weird error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you use your `ReportViewer` component but if you use `LocalReport` property then you can onway set your parameters in `.aspx` codeBehind page like this:

```
YourReporViewer.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter("startDate", TextBox1.Value));
```

You also can do it with `ServerReport` property.

For more detailed information you can [read this](http://www.csharpcourses.com/2008/06/how-to-pass-parameters-to-reporting.html).

Comment: Tried: ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter("fromDate", TextBox1.Text));   Got an error message: LocalProcessingException was unhandled by user code.  An error occurred during local report processing.  I do have a aggregate MIN(rDateTime) which I named [fromDate] in the SQL command and report.

Comment: i said it depend on how you define your report and how you use it. You should show it. I just don't understand what's going on

Comment: trying to re-edit my question for further details, but there isn't much details, just how to I get the report viewer to display the date the user puts into a text box.  with rdlc reports and asp.net

Comment: @K.Taylor and you know that you can create paremeters in .rdlc file? And it could create inputs for this parameters?

Comment: I tried originally just making parameters in the report through a data adapter in the data set, but every time I do it changes the parameters names in the SQL statement to '?' instead, when I load the report designer from that there are no parameters fields in the report.

Comment: OK got it, your create a parameters was the hint I needed.  I was using data fields as parameters with a min and max from SQL command.  But I figured out how to make simple parameters in the parameters field from the report data tab in the rdlc report and the code you suggested YourReporViewer.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter("startDate", TextBox1.Value)); worked to fill those in.  Thanks.